# Looping Through Properties and accessing its own properties

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I am new to C# and Umbraco. Can't figured this simple thing out nor find the solutions

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = null;
}
List<string> test = new List<string>();
var item = CurrentPage.Children.FirstOrDefault();
var count = 0;
foreach (var prop in item.Properties) {
    count++;
    test.Add(prop.PropertyTypeAlias);
}
<html>
...
</html>
```

If i count properties it gives correct number of properties but i can't get access its own properties such as "Value", "PropertyTypeAlias" etc. It throw exception reads:
`Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyTypeAlias'`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you get rid of the var words and replace them with the types you really expect? This to make it a bit more readable. Can you also place the using on top, you say it is umbraco related but I see also some reflection in the code?

Comment: @aldert I edited. Nothing really much going on top actually. It's simple razor template and i'm using `CurrentPage` to access data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access properties of a document type, it's better and easier to do it like this:

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@{

}

<h1>@Model.Content.Name</h1>
@foreach (var item in Model.Content.Children)
{
    <h2>@(item.GetPropertyValue<IHtmlString>("bodyText"))</h2>
}
```

CurrentPage is a dynamic object, whereas Model.Content gets the "current page", but as a strongly-typed IPublishedContent, which means, if you use Visual Studio, you get intellisense and can see which methods you can use.

In the H1-tag, I simply pulled out the current content node's name, in the foreach, I am looping over the current content node's children and displaying their property with alias "bodyText" and datatype "Rich text".

EDIT:

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    var child = Model.Content.Children.FirstOrDefault();
    var properties = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in child.Properties)
    {
        properties.Add(item.PropertyTypeAlias);
    }
}
@foreach (var item in properties)
{
    <h1>@item</h1>
}
```

Comment: I am looping through first child's properties. In your example you are looping through children and get property value by name. Even though i understand the part about Model vs CurrentPage it's not helping with my problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. In the end, all problem caused by `CurrentPage`. I will try to avoid using it next time.

Comment: Yepp - When you're using Model.Content you're also more likely to get more specific error messages than when using a dynamic :)